# clickonce-deploy missing microsoft dll

Tags: wpf, deployment, clickonce

When I create a clickonce deploy of a wpf application many microsft dll's are missing in the deployment.

f.e. `system.dll`, `system.data.dll`, `system.reactive.core.dll`, system.xaml.dll, ...

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you still need to install the .NET Framework on the computer on which you want to install the ClickOnce application, it doesn't make much sense to include these assemblies in the deployment. They should be available in the GAC anyway.

You can include any other assemblies - including the system.reactive.* ones - by including them under Project->Properties->Publish->Application Files... in Visual Studio before you publish.

If you set the `Copy Local` property of these assembluies to `True` in the Solution Explorer, they should be included by default.

Note that if these assemblies are referenced from another project than the one you publish, you should copy the references to the WPF application project that you publish. If they are part of a NuGet package you should also add that NuGet package to the project being published.

Comment: I test the deployment on my dev machine and without them, the app is not running, although all sdk's have been installed on my machine.

Comment: The test-machine = my development machine. Yes I have .Net 4.7.2 installed on it (= target framework of app)

Comment: So what error message are you getting? And why do you ask for suggestions on why some assemblies are missing from the output folder?

Comment: System.NullreferenceException. Add the missing dll's to the folder and exception is gone.

Comment: system.reactive.core.dll is not a framework assembly and should be included in the publish. When do you get the exception?

Comment: at launch of the application

Comment: manually added just the system.reactive.* dll's that are in the build project and app launches correctly. How to add them in the publish, the are not in the list of file one can select to include.

Comment: Did you read my answer? Include these assemblies under Project->Properties->Publish->Application Files... You might also set the Copy Local property of them to true in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: system.reactive.* is not in the list

Comment: Set the Copy Local property to true in the reference list in Solution Exporer then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172425/discussion-between-brilbroeder-and-mm8).

Comment: suggestion by @mm8 : install nuget packages used in referenced project in the main project (although) they are not needed and the missing dll's will be included in the publication.